Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.5.0'] was not found in any of the following sources
CONTEXT: Im using android studio and trying to update an app to the newest API (34) and publish into google play store.
ERROR:
* Where:
Build file '...android\app\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.5.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.5.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    //noinspection AndroidGradlePluginVersion
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.5.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.22' apply false
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.application'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appID"
        minSdkVersion 21
        compileSdk 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    ndkVersion '25.1.8937393'
    compileSdk 34
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

}


My android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

rootProject.layout.buildDirectory = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.layout.buildDirectory = "${rootProject.layout.buildDirectory}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}
subprojects {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
        tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.layout.buildDirectory
    }

    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                                    if (namespace == null) {
                                    namespace project.group
                                }
            }
        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   }
}

My gradle settings:
dependencyResolutionManagement {

    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()

    }
}

rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'

project(':app').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'company/android/app/')

android/settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.5.0'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version ''1.9.22'
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2'
}

include ":app"

gradle-wrapper-properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

I tried to check all the version compatibility but keep facing the same error.

First of all use targetSdk 34 instead of compileSdk 34 in your app/build.gradle.

Realized i used a wrong file for my app/build.gradle. Did an edit to rectify it.

Try to change the version from here.

But there is existing version 8.5.0 for com.android.application, no?

Yes there is existing version but I have seen same issue in other questions - 71780967 76620079 78230724. And most answers are like changing the versions

Two things:

The Gradle settings.gradle file needs to be in the root folder of your project. Such a file in the subproject folders has no effect, so I am not sure why you have ended up with such a file in your android folder.
The Android plugins are not stored at the Gradle plugin portal (the error message shows that this is the only location Gradle is looking for plugins) so you need to tell Gradle to look in the Google repository as well by adding the following to your (root) settings.gradle file:

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

